# string extraction in bash/mysql count of updated rows

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

This may be a trivial thing but I cannot find it anywhere...
I have a variable,

> UPDATED="-------------- UPDATE table SET column = 'value' WHERE condition = 'true' -------------- Query OK, 3 rows affected Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0 Bye"

I would like to get `3` from the variable `$UPDATED`. It could be anything, sometimes it is 0, and other times non zero (single digit, double digits, etc.)

How do I get that value of how many rows were updated. I found that using `-vvv` to the mysql query gives the above text and so I'm using it. If there are any other easier ways to get the count of rows updated, then even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep

```
echo "${UPDATED}"| grep -Po  "[0-9]*(?= rows)"
```

Comment: It is throwing this error, `sh: 21: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: ok, seems your system doesn't support `<<<`, I updated , can you try again?

Comment: you have to quote variable

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is getting the number of rows which were affected by your `UPDATE` statement, then you can simply use `[ROW_COUNT][1]` method to get that.

```
UPDATE table SET column = value;
SELECT row_count() INTO variable;
```

In your bash script, you can do this, where affected_rows is a variable which will store the value of the command

```
affected_rows='`mysql -h [hostname] -u[user] -p[pass] -e UPDATE table SET column = value; SELECT row_count();`';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I don't know the syntax for it. I wrote as is and it is throwing an error - undeclared variable. I'm fairly new to all this so can you please help me with the exact statements?

Comment: You need to declare the variable into which you are reading the value from row_count(). So just declare the variable in your program and you would be good to go.

Comment: I'm using mysql block as follows - `$MYSQL -h $MHOST -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $i << EOFMYSQL

declare updated_count=0;
UPDATE table SET colum = value;

SELECT row_count() INTO updated_count;

EOFMYSQL`  But it is still giving me the error `ERROR 1327 (42000) at line 4: Undeclared variable: updated_count`

Comment: see my edit. You don't need to know the variable name.

Comment: It is giving the entire query in `echo $affected_rows` as opposed to just the count.